# Install an app from SD card programmatically

Tags: android

I am using this code to install an app from SD card

```
Toast.makeText(this, "running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    .setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/app.apk"), 
                    "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(promptInstall);
```

how ever I am getting parse error : There was a problem parsing the package

I have given the permission in manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

I have placed the apk in sdcard

ps: app is getting installed via file manager

Comment: Are you sure that .apk file is correct? Did you try to install it from filemanager? Also I lookedat my code, I have this intent flag in my code 
        **intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);**

Comment: Never hardcode paths. Use methods (e.g., ones on `Environment`) to access external storage. It is entirely possible that your path is wrong. Also, unless you are part of a custom ROM, you cannot hold `INSTALL_PACKAGES`, though you do not need that permission for installing an APK via an `Intent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the way you specify the URI. try this;

```
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                .setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"<DIRECTORY_NAME>"+File.separator+"<YOUR_APK_FILE.apk>")),
        "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(promptInstall);
```

Comment: please share the logcat